# Getting career advice from different people

Tags: career-path, cv

If looking for career advice and short recommendations for paths to end up in a specific institute, is it ok to ask for some answers from different people in the same institute, like one who is likely involved in the admission process and another who has an interesting career path him/herself?

Or might it be weird if the two found out they received an inquiry for career advice from the same person? After all, I don't want to spam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly fine (and indeed sensible) to ask for career advice from more than one person. Different people can contribute different perspectives. It's also entirely ok to approach people for advice and tell them that you are approaching others too - rather than being weird it shows that you are curious and trying to get as much information and feedback as possible.